# Is the un-detonated globe of Otiluke's Freezing Sphere magical?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, duration

[*Otiluke's Freezing Sphere*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/freezing-sphere) has an interesting "delayed blast" feature, which involves creating and handling a physical globe containing the spell's energy:

> You can refrain from firing the globe after completing the spell, if you wish. A small globe about the size of a sling stone, cool to the touch, appears in your hand. At any time, you or a creature you give the globe to can throw the globe (to a range of 40 feet) or hurl it with a sling (to the sling’s normal range). It shatters on impact, with the same effect as the normal casting of the spell. You can also set the globe down without shattering it. After 1 minute, if the globe hasn’t already shattered, it explodes.

However, the duration of the spell is instantaneous. So I wonder what would happen if the globe of a previously-cast *Freezing Sphere* spell were tossed into an antimagic field. Or what would happen if I cast *Dispel Magic* on the globe. Would the globe disappear, or is it no longer considered magical and thus immune to these effects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 5e, the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=17) provides an official ruling for determining what counts as magical (see the response to "Is the breath weapon of a dragon magical?"):

> Determining whether a game feature is magical is straightforward. Ask yourself these questions about the feature:
>
> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell that’s mentioned in its description?
> - Is it a spell attack?
> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
> - Does its description say it’s magical?
>
> If your answer to any of those questions is yes, the feature is magical.

In this case, the spell description states:

> It shatters on impact, **with the same effect as the normal casting of the spell**.

This satisfies bullet point 2 and thus the orb is itself magical.

Comment: I've edited the answer to cite the source of that "litmus test" and explain that it's an official ruling (and updated it to match the Sage Advice Compendium version which now also includes "Is it fueled by spell slots?"). Please review the answer and make sure it still matches your intent.